# Amazon SES - PHPMailer - Connection Refused

Tags: php, email, connection, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I am trying to send mail using PHPMailer to Amazon SES via SMTP, and keep getting this error:

```
    2022-09-03 13:45:38 Connection: opening to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
    2022-09-03 13:45:46 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587 (Connection refused) [/home/xxx/public_html/Classes/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php line 389]
    2022-09-03 13:45:46 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
    SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

My PHP code is as follows:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host='email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->Username='*********';  // I am sure this is correct
$mail->Password='*********';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->setFrom('me@example.com', 'My Test');  //me@example.com is verified in Amazon SES
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
$mail->Subject = $subject;  // $subject, $message are set
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->addAddress('to@example.com');     // to@example.com has been verified in Amazon SES
$mail->send();
```

My hosting provider assures me they are not blocking outbound SMTP on port 587.
Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If your hosting provider isn’t also AWS, I’d expect you would need to apply appropriate security groups and permissions to the SMTP service before you can connect to it. I’d check AWS docs

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere on your machine or your hosting provider's network, port 587 is blocked (at least to this host, but probably any host). Connection refused is an error on TCP level (so before TLS is set up or credentials are exchanged) so it must be a firewall rule somewhere.

You should be able to validate this by opening telnet on your machine and verify whether you can connect (or not).

Try this:

```
telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 587
```

You should be seeing something like this:

```
Trying 3.93.129.192...
Connected to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-d-4BGMRGTLJ 
J3pR3SR7dynD7p1lAScN
```

If you see something else, or get an error, it's some firewall issue. Note that it may be on your local server as well. It will not be an issue with AWS SES as you do not need to enable access in security groups for SES, SES will allow connections from any source.